# Changing chmod flags back

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions, chmod

I'm fairly new to the whole UNIX / command shell sort of stuff, so I apologize for any ignorance for something I am not aware of. And by new, I mean extremely new.

I was confused by how to change a file's permissions back to the way they were before. I have the output for the file's permissions from "ls -l filename" before they were changed, and I am just trying to revert them back to the way they were.

I need to make the file ("install.php") to have the following permissions (as given to me by "ls -l install.php"):

```
rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 620
```

What would be the proper syntax of the chmod command to make this file have the above permissions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just type `man chmod` and it will show you How to use the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Its very simple binary
first 3 rwx is for the owner - 110 a 6
second 3 rwx is for group - 100 - a 4
third 3 rwx is for other - 100 a 4

in your scenario chmod 644 filename